# Style a string within a paragraph with an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<p>
   (rcvd)                           
<a href="linkhere">Title</a>
   by Person,                          
<br></br>
   - More text            
</p>
```

And I want to change the color of (rcvd) to green.  I tried the following:

1. This changes the entire line to green but keeps the link

   $("p:contains('(rcvd)')").attr("style","color:green");
2. This changes the rcvd part to green but removes the Title link

   ```
   $("p").each(function() {
       var text = $(this).text();
       text = text.replace("(rcvd)", "<span style='color:green;'>(rcvd)</span>");
       $(this).html(text);
   });
   ```
3. This does nothing, but I think it's the solution I want with a small tweak somewhere that I'm missing

   ```
   $(p).html($(p).html().replace("(rcvd)","<span style='color:green;'>(rcvd)</span>"));
   ```

Any pointers welcome (I am still new to JQuery and trying to learn so I'd love an explanation as to why you make the suggestion you make.

Comment: I'm quite sure that number three is the solution - you should use `each()` to iterate over your `p`s, that should do. Otherwise, David Thomas' answer should do the same.

Comment: You are only losing content in your 2nd example as you are getting "text()" (i.e. raw text) but saving it back as "html()". That is throwing away any HTML in the paragraphs. Get and set as html and it will work. (Please use a classname and css rather than hard-wire the color though) :)

Comment: The third example is wrong as it use "all paragraphs" to obtain the html to place in "all paragraphs".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My own suggestion would be:

```
$('p').html(function(i,h){
    return h.replace('(rcvd)', '<span class="greenColoured">(rcvd)</span>');
});
```

Using CSS to supply the style:

```
.greenColoured {
    color: green;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ypSpZ/1/).

As noted by [TrueBlueAussie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982939/style-a-string-within-a-paragraph-with-an-id/18983031?noredirect=1#comment28040241_18983031) (in comments, below), I've not explained the parameters in the anonymous function passed to the `html()` method: the `function(i, h)`:

The `html()` method essentially iterates over the collection returned by the selector (in this case over all the paragraphs selected); without use of the anonymous function each `p` element would have the same HTML set. Using the function, with the `i` and `v` (which can be named however you please allows you to access the index (`i`) of the currently iterated-over element amongst the collection, and `v` (the second parameter) returns the current 'value' (in this case the existing `innerHTML` of the current node being iterated over).

As noted, these parameters can be called anything you like, for me `i` and `h` are habitual (`i` for 'index' and `h` for `HTML` in this case); so long as you remember that (as with many other anonymous functions passed to jQuery methods) the *first* is the index and the second the 'current-value'.

References:

- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: Can you explain your use of a function as a parameter to html() for the uninitiated? e.g. http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml. This is my favorite answer so far (and you used a class instead of inline colors, although the classname should reflect the attribute "oktogo" rather than the implementation "green").

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: I've updated the answer to *try* and explain that; does that work for you? (I mean this genuinely; I'm not quite sure how to *explain* it.) As for the class-name, I sort of agree; but I couldn't think of a class-name that was more suited and there didn't seem to be an expressed preference in the question itself, so I went with the obvious 'intent,' I guess.

Answer (score 3):

This will select the first node within the P (which happens to be a text node) and style it:

```
$("p").contents().first().wrap("<span style='color:green'></span>");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jrAWn/

**UPDATED**. Ok, and this is using class:

```
.rStyle {
   color:green;     
}

$("p").contents().first().wrap("<span/>").parent().addClass("rStyle");
```

Comment: Well, that's a nice snippet - didn't know `contents()` exists - seems great

Comment: Style belongs in the CSS... set a class instead of hard-wiring colors.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie you're right, but this is a proof of concept snippet, no production code ;)

Comment: True, just suggesting you improve your answer a little (which you can do at any time). No point encouraging bad habits in newbies :)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the tag names in quotes [(jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/n5LNH/):

```
$("p").html($("p").html().replace("(rcvd)","<span style='color:green;'>(rcvd)</span>"));
```

At the moment you are passing the variable `p` to the jQuery function. Presumable `p` is undefined, so you either get a Javascript error or just an empty jQuery object.

As others have said, the standard way to do this is wrapping the rvcd in a span:

```
<p>
   <span class="style-this">(rcvd)</span>                           
<a href="linkhere">Title</a>
   by Person,                          
<br></br>
   - More text            
</p>
```

And

```
$(".style-this").css("color", "green");
```

Comment: Style belongs in the CSS... set a class instead of hard-wiring colors. Then this would be cleaner and would get my vote.

Comment: While I agree with this answer, I'm working in a system where I can't control the HTML in this way, I have to work within what the system is providing.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `css()` and give your `<p>` tag a class:

```
<p id="myGreenClass">(rcvd)</p>
```

And this jQuery code:

```
$('.myGreenClass').css('color', 'green');
```

Comment: The (rcvd) is only part of the paragraph, so this will not work. You will make the link and the remaining text green as well... needs a span around the specific text.